# CC2540 USB - make discoverable: Not ready to perform task

Tags: bluetooth, usb, bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments

I am using the TI CC2540 USB dongle in peripheral mode and want to enable advertising, using BTool, but the device is answering:

> Not Ready To Perform Task

I know that it's possible to set initial advertising enable in the application code, but I want to set advertising manually, can someone help out?
Here is the log of BTool:

```
[1] : <Tx> - 04:52:52.802
-Type       : 0x01 (Command)
-Opcode     : 0xFE00 (GAP_DeviceInit)
-Data Length    : 0x26 (38) byte(s)
 ProfileRole    : 0x04 (Peripheral)
 MaxScanRsps    : 0x05 (5)
 IRK        : 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 CSRK       : 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SignCounter    : 0x00000001 (1)

[2] : <Rx> - 04:52:52.878
-Type       : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode  : 0xFF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) bytes(s)
 Event      : 0x067F (GAP_HCI_ExtentionCommandStatus)
 Status     : 0x00 (Success)
 OpCode     : 0xFE00 (GAP_DeviceInit)
 DataLength : 0x00 (0)

[3] : <Rx> - 04:52:52.950
-Type       : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode  : 0xFF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x2C (44) bytes(s)
 Event      : 0x0600 (GAP_DeviceInitDone)
 Status     : 0x00 (Success)
 DevAddr        : C0:FF:EE:C0:FF:EE
 DataPktLen : 0x001B (27)
 NumDataPkts    : 0x04 (4)
 IRK        : 67:76:7D:A8:78:A1:A8:61:71:BD:58:24:92:39:0E:EC
 CSRK       : 4E:EA:B7:B5:14:34:66:8C:2D:6B:29:9D:C9:1E:4F:16

[4] : <Tx> - 04:53:00.375
-Type       : 0x01 (Command)
-Opcode     : 0xFE06 (GAP_MakeDiscoverable)
-Data Length    : 0x0F (15) byte(s)
 EventType  : 0x00 (Connectable Undirect Advertisement)
 InitAddrType   : 0x00 (Public)
 InitAddrs      : 00:00:00:00:00:00
 ChannelMap : 0x07 (Channel 37
          Channel 38
          Channel 39)
 FilterPolicy   : 0x00 (Allow Scan Requests From Any, Allow 
          Connect Request From Any.)

[5] : <Rx> - 04:53:00.455
-Type       : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode  : 0xFF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) bytes(s)
 Event      : 0x067F (GAP_HCI_ExtentionCommandStatus)
 Status     : 0x10 (Not Ready To Perform Task)
 OpCode     : 0xFE06 (GAP_MakeDiscoverable)
 DataLength : 0x00 (0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this sequence is detectable.

```
[12] : <Tx> - 08:30:57.212
-Type       : 0x01 (Command)
-Opcode     : 0xFE00 (GAP_DeviceInit)
-Data Length    : 0x26 (38) byte(s)
 ProfileRole    : 0x04 (Peripheral)
 MaxScanRsps    : 0x05 (5)
 IRK        : 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 CSRK       : 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SignCounter    : 0x00000001 (1)
Dump(Tx):
01 00 FE 26 04 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
```

---

```
[13] : <Rx> - 08:30:57.291
-Type       : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode  : 0xFF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) bytes(s)
 Event      : 0x067F (GAP_HCI_ExtentionCommandStatus)
 Status     : 0x00 (Success)
 OpCode     : 0xFE00 (GAP_DeviceInit)
 DataLength : 0x00 (0)
Dump(Rx):
04 FF 06 7F 06 00 00 FE 00
```

---

```
[14] : <Rx> - 08:30:57.356
-Type       : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode  : 0xFF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x2C (44) bytes(s)
 Event      : 0x0600 (GAP_DeviceInitDone)
 Status     : 0x00 (Success)
 DevAddr        : 00:18:30:EA:9C:1B
 DataPktLen : 0x001B (27)
 NumDataPkts    : 0x04 (4)
 IRK        : E2:7D:76:4B:9B:24:8D:EA:F8:A6:E3:82:16:C8:C5:0C
 CSRK       : EE:68:E6:8E:F6:48:43:04:C4:F0:5C:D3:D1:39:A9:9F
Dump(Rx):
04 FF 2C 00 06 00 1B 9C EA 30 18 00 1B 00 04 E2 
7D 76 4B 9B 24 8D EA F8 A6 E3 82 16 C8 C5 0C EE 
68 E6 8E F6 48 43 04 C4 F0 5C D3 D1 39 A9 9F
```

---

```
[15] : <Tx> - 08:31:04.155
-Type       : 0x01 (Command)
-Opcode     : 0xFE07 (GAP_UpdateAdvertisingData)
-Data Length    : 0x05 (5) byte(s)
 AdType     : 0x01 (Advertisement data)
 DataLength : 0x03 (3)
 AdvertData : 02:01:06
Dump(Tx):
01 07 FE 05 01 03 02 01 06
```

---

```
[16] : <Rx> - 08:31:04.231
-Type       : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode  : 0xFF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) bytes(s)
 Event      : 0x067F (GAP_HCI_ExtentionCommandStatus)
 Status     : 0x00 (Success)
 OpCode     : 0xFE07 (GAP_UpdateAdvertisingData)
 DataLength : 0x00 (0)
Dump(Rx):
04 FF 06 7F 06 00 07 FE 00
```

---

```
[17] : <Rx> - 08:31:04.296
-Type       : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode  : 0xFF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x04 (4) bytes(s)
 Event      : 0x0602 (GAP_AdvertDataUpdate)
 Status     : 0x00 (Success)
 AdType     : 0x01 (Advertisement data)
Dump(Rx):
04 FF 04 02 06 00 01
```

---

```
[18] : <Tx> - 08:31:06.786
-Type       : 0x01 (Command)
-Opcode     : 0xFE06 (GAP_MakeDiscoverable)
-Data Length    : 0x0F (15) byte(s)
 EventType  : 0x00 (Connectable Undirect Advertisement)
 InitAddrType   : 0x00 (Public)
 InitAddrs      : 00:00:00:00:00:00
 ChannelMap : 0x07 (Channel 37
              Channel 38
              Channel 39)
 FilterPolicy   : 0x00 (Allow Scan Requests From Any, Allow 
              Connect Request From Any.)
Dump(Tx):
01 06 FE 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 
00 00 00
```

---

```
[19] : <Rx> - 08:31:06.858
-Type       : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode  : 0xFF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x06 (6) bytes(s)
 Event      : 0x067F (GAP_HCI_ExtentionCommandStatus)
 Status     : 0x00 (Success)
 OpCode     : 0xFE06 (GAP_MakeDiscoverable)
 DataLength : 0x00 (0)
Dump(Rx):
04 FF 06 7F 06 00 06 FE 00
```

---

```
[20] : <Rx> - 08:31:06.923
-Type       : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode  : 0xFF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length    : 0x05 (5) bytes(s)
 Event      : 0x0603 (GAP_MakeDiscoverable)
 Status     : 0x00 (Success)
Dump(Rx):
04 FF 05 03 06 00 E8 01
```

Answer (score 2):

using prebuilt HostTestRelease project on dongle and setting it to peripheral mode, I got after several trials the following success code:

[73] :  - 02:13:30.416
-Type : 0x01 (Command)
-Opcode : 0xFE07 (GAP_UpdateAdvertisingData)
-Data Length : 0x05 (5) byte(s)
AdType : 0x01 (Advertisement data)
DataLength : 0x03 (3)
AdvertData : 02:01:06
Dump(Tx):
01 07 FE 05 01 03 02 01 06

---

[74] :  - 02:13:30.493
-Type : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode : 0xFF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length : 0x06 (6) bytes(s)
Event : 0x067F (GAP_HCI_ExtentionCommandStatus)
Status : 0x00 (Success)
OpCode : 0xFE07 (GAP_UpdateAdvertisingData)
DataLength : 0x00 (0)
Dump(Rx):
04 FF 06 7F 06 00 07 FE 00

---

[75] :  - 02:13:30.566
-Type : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode : 0xFF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length : 0x04 (4) bytes(s)
Event : 0x0602 (GAP_AdvertDataUpdate)
Status : 0x00 (Success)
AdType : 0x01 (Advertisement data)
Dump(Rx):
04 FF 04 02 06 00 01

---

[76] :  - 02:14:04.382
-Type : 0x01 (Command)
-Opcode : 0xFE06 (GAP_MakeDiscoverable)
-Data Length : 0x0F (15) byte(s)
EventType : 0x04 (Scan Response)
InitAddrType : 0x00 (Public)
InitAddrs : 00:00:00:00:00:00
ChannelMap : 0x07 (Channel 37
Channel 38
Channel 39)
FilterPolicy : 0x00 (Allow Scan Requests From Any, Allow
Connect Request From Any.)
Dump(Tx):
01 06 FE 0F 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 00
00 00 00

---

[77] :  - 02:14:04.456
-Type : 0x04 (Event)
-EventCode : 0xFF (HCI_LE_ExtEvent)
-Data Length : 0x06 (6) bytes(s)
Event : 0x067F (GAP_HCI_ExtentionCommandStatus)
Status : 0x00 (Success)
OpCode : 0xFE06 (GAP_MakeDiscoverable)
DataLength : 0x00 (0)
Dump(Rx):
04 FF 06 7F 06 00 06 FE 00

Hope it'll be useful!